Макрос Checkbox
Есть макрос:
For i = 1 To 6
If ("CheckBox" & i) = False Then  
      MsgBox "TEST", vbOKOnly
End If
  Next i

в итоге в скобках получаем сцепление
"CheckBox1",..."CheckBox6"
т.е. макрос не работает.
Вопрос как убрать кавычки что бы получилось CheckBox1

С библиотекой разобрался, была ссылка на удаленную надстройку. Но теперь ругается на Controls: Sub not defined

Леонид, для вас: Я случайно создал две учётные записи, как их объединить?
